# elasticsearch: how to add input value with existing value for integer field

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a document existing in ES like this:

```
{
    "noteCount": 1,
    ....
}
```

there is another incoming document like this:

```
{
    "noteCount": 2,
    ....
}
```

While updating the ES document, for the `noteCount` object, I need to save it as 3 which is 1 + 2.
Any way I can make it work?

Comment: Do you want to update which document?

Comment: yes. I need to update the existing document with the calculated noteCount

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [painless scripting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting-painless.html) with an [update query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update.html).

```
PUT /test/_doc/1?pretty
{
  "noteCount" : 1,
  "tags" : ["red"]
}

POST /test/_update/1?pretty
{
  "script" : {
    "source": "ctx._source.noteCount += params.count",
    "lang": "painless",
    "params" : {
      "count" : 1
    }
  }
}

GET /test/_doc/1
```

Comment: can I make the params dynamically ? basically I need the new noteCount = current noteCount + incoming noteCount. Current noteCount is what saved in ES already. Does it make sense?

Comment: Yeah so params.count is reading value from "params" object in which we have specified "count" is 1. You can pass 5 instead of 1 or any dynamic number. Even you can change name "count" field name in params object. You can just follow the example which i have given, you will get the idea.

Comment: how to get the existing noteCount which saved in ES and pass it to params.Count?

Comment: You dont need to pass explicitly. This expression "ctx._source.noteCount += params.count" will take care of it. Whatever number is present on noteCount it will simply increment by 1 (as we specified count:1)

Comment: ohhh so ctx._source is the current document value? so I will just need to add it with the incoming params.count?

Comment: Yes ctx._source.noteCount is holding current value

Comment: I would recommend to perform above quick demo. It will give you more clarity. Also mark it correct if its really helped you :) Thanks